# Copying a rsa public key to clipboard

Tags: macos, ssh, clipboard

I am trying to copy a public key to the clipboard on macOS, but I keep getting "no such file or directory." The command I am using is pasted below

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: Generate SSH key 
```ssh-keygen -t rsa```
and then copy SSH key using 
```cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy```

Answer (score 151):

To copy your public key to the clipboard

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

This pipes the output of the file to pbcopy.

Comment: Worked macOS 10.14 (Mojave)

Answer (score 133):

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

then you can copy your ssh key

Answer (score 43):

Another alternative solution, that is recommended in the github help pages:

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Should this fail, I recommend using their docs to trouble shoot or generate a new key - if not already done.

[Github docs](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/)

Comment: That’s what OP already has. It’s the correct solution on macOS though, so +1.

Answer (score 31):

Check the path where you have generated the public key. You can also copy the `id_rsa` by using this command:

```
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: that's the command github lists in there help section. But when I'm trying to use it I get following output:
`bash: /usr/bin/clip: No such file or directory`

Comment: that helped me on windows

Comment: `xclip` is also a potential option on some legacy systems.

Answer (score 20):

Your command is right, but the error shows that you didn't create your ssh key yet. To generate new ssh key enter the following command into the terminal.

```
ssh-keygen
```

After entering the command then you will be asked to enter file name and passphrase. Normally you don't need to change this. Just press enter. Then your key will be generated in `~/.ssh` directory. After this, you can copy your key by the following command.

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

or

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

You can find more about this here [ssh](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/).

Answer (score 17):

Windows:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Mac OS:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | pbcopy
```

Comment: Easy and works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

For using Git bash on Windows:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub > /dev/clipboard
```

*(modified from Jupiter St John's [post on Coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/pmduxw/copy-files-to-clipboard-in-windows-git-bash))*

Answer (score 6):

With PowerShell on Windows, you can use:

```bsh
Get-Content ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | Set-Clipboard
```

Answer (score 3):

**To copy your public ssh key on a Windows machine you can do:**

Go to the "/ssh" folder

```
cd  C:\Users\<your-user>\.ssh\
```

List to see the keys

```
ls ~/.ssh
```

Copy the public key to clipboard(starts with "id_" and ends with ".pub")

```
type id_xxxxxxx.pub | clip
```

Answer (score 2):

Does the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` exist? If not, you need to generate one first:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative solution:

```
cat  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub |  xsel -i -b
```

From `man xsel` :

> -i, --input
>
> read standard input into the selection.
>
> -b, --clipboard
>
> operate on the CLIPBOARD selection.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP mentions one possible ssh key file name (`id_rsa.pub`), no one has mentioned that there are different possible names for your ssh key.
Github accepts three, for example:

```
id_rsa.pub
id_ecdsa.pub
id_ed25519.pub
```

You would be better off checking if you have *any* keys, such as:

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh
# Lists the files in your .ssh directory, if they exist
```

Based on what you find, then use your copy command, such as

```
pbcopy < ~/.ssh/<your_key>
```

See [Github's Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/checking-for-existing-ssh-keys) on checking for existing keys.

Answer (score -1):

```
cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | bcopy
```

This works for me.